# TSQL query to concatenate and remove common prefix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data

```
id    ref
==   ==========
1    3536757616
1    3536757617
1    3536757618
```

and want to get the result

```
1    3536757616/7/8
```

so essentially the data is aggregated on id, with the refs concatenated together, separated by a slash '/', but with any common prefix removed so if the data was like

```
id    ref
==   ==========
2    3536757628
2    3536757629
2    3536757630
```

I would want to get the result

```
2    3536757629/28/30
```

I know I can simply concatenate the refs by using

```
SELECT distinct
    id,
    stuff ( ( SELECT
                  '/ ' + ref 
              FROM
                  tableA tableA_1
              where tableA_1.id = tableA_2.id
    FOR XML PATH ( '' ) ) , 1 , 2 , '' )
from TableA tableA_2
```

to give

```
1   3536757616/ 3536757617/ 3536757618
2   3536757628/ 3536757629/ 3536757630
```

but it's the bit that removes the common element that I'm after.....

---

Code for test data :

```
create table tableA (id int, ref varchar(50))

insert into tableA
select 1, 3536757616
union select 1, 3536757617
union select 1, 3536757618
union select 2, 3536757628
union select 2, 3536757629
union select 2, 3536757630
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH hier(cnt) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  cnt + 1
        FROM    hier
        WHERE   cnt <= 100
        )
SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) = 1 THEN ref ELSE ' / ' + SUBSTRING(ref, mc + 1, LEN(ref)) END 
FROM    (
        SELECT  MIN(common) AS mc
        FROM    (
                SELECT  (
                        SELECT  MAX(cnt)
                        FROM    hier
                        WHERE   SUBSTRING(initref, 1, cnt) = SUBSTRING(ref, 1, cnt)
                                AND cnt <= LEN(ref)
                        ) AS common
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  TOP 1 ref AS initref
                        FROM    tableA
                        ) i,
                        tableA
                ) q
        ) q2, tableA
FOR XML PATH('')

---

3536757616 / 17 / 18 / 28 / 29 / 30
```

Same thing with groups:

```
WITH hier(cnt) AS
        (
        SELECT  1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  cnt + 1
        FROM    hier
        WHERE   cnt <= 100
        )
SELECT  (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a2.ref) = 1 THEN ref ELSE ' / ' + SUBSTRING(ref, mc + 1, LEN(ref)) END 
        FROM    tableA a2
        WHERE   a2.id = q2.id
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, MIN(common) AS mc
        FROM    (
                SELECT  a.id,
                        (
                        SELECT  MAX(cnt)
                        FROM    hier
                        WHERE   SUBSTRING(i.initref, 1, cnt) = SUBSTRING(a.ref, 1, cnt)
                                AND cnt <= LEN(ref)
                        ) AS common
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  id, MIN(ref) AS initref
                        FROM    tableA
                        GROUP BY
                                id
                        ) i
                JOIN    tableA a
                ON      i.id = a.id
                ) q
        GROUP BY
                id
        ) q2
---
3536757616 / 7 / 8
3536757628 / 29 / 30
```

Comment: +1. My head hurts trying to wrap my brain around this but it sure is a "very" nice way of doing it. Far superiour than the (currently) other two answers (including my own).

Comment: @Lieven: will be the subject of tomorrow's post in my blog

Comment: just add id to the final select and it's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I named my table #T, and using the following SELECT statement

```
select id, number, substring(#t.ref, 1, v.number), count(id)
from master.dbo.spt_values v
inner join #t on v.number <= len(#t.ref)
where v.name is null and v.number > 0 
group by id, number, substring(#t.ref, 1, v.number)
order by id, count(id) desc, number desc
```

you get a result set where the first record of each id contains the maximum length and the longest initial string for each id.

That's not a complete solution, but a good starting point: iterate over the id's, issue a SELECT TOP 1 to retrieve the longest string, and concatenate the string diffs for each record with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @tableA table(id int, ref varchar(50))
declare @suffix table(id int, suffix varchar(50))
declare @todo table(id int)

insert into @tableA
select 1, '3536757616'
union select 1, '3536757617'
union select 1, '3536757618'
union select 2, '3536757628'
union select 2, '3536757629'
union select 2, '3536757630'

insert into @suffix
select * from @tableA

insert into @todo
select s1.id
from (
    select id, cnt = count(*)
    from @suffix
    group by id, substring(suffix, 1, 1) 
  ) s1 
  inner join (
    select id, cnt = count(*)
    from @suffix
    group by id
  ) s2 on s2.id = s1.id and s2.cnt = s1.cnt

while exists (select * from @todo)
begin
  update @suffix
  set suffix = substring(suffix, 2, len(suffix) - 1)
  from @suffix s
       inner join @todo t on t.id = s.id

  delete from @todo

  insert into @todo
  select s1.id
  from (
      select id, cnt = count(*)
      from @suffix
      group by id, substring(suffix, 1, 1) 
    ) s1 
    inner join (
      select id, cnt = count(*)
      from @suffix
      group by id
    ) s2 on s2.id = s1.id and s2.cnt = s1.cnt  
end

select * from @suffix
```