# Compile single string from sql results

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TSQL query to concatenate and remove common prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944160/tsql-query-to-concatenate-and-remove-common-prefix)

Hi

How does one compile a single string from the results of an SQL query.

E.g.

```
Table A
Column: Name
Row 0 : John
Row 1 : Sam
Row 2 : Kate
```

Resulting SQL query must return a single row with the result as a single string.

E.g.

```
"John, Sam, Kate"
```

Note: Using MS SQL 2005

Comment: Duplicate of at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944160 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852, probably many more...

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I usually use, just remove the table and add your own:

```
DECLARE @A
  TABLE ( Name VARCHAR(50) );

INSERT INTO @A ([Name]) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO @A ([Name]) VALUES ('Sam');
INSERT INTO @A ([Name]) VALUES ('Kate');

SELECT REPLACE((SELECT [Name] AS [data()]
  FROM @A
   FOR XML PATH('')
     ) , ' ', ', ') [Concatenated]
```

Should result in:

```
Concatenated
-------------------
John, Sam, Kate
```

Answer (score 2):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-)

**EDIT**

Equivalent can be seen [here](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a cursor. Something like this (from [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)) should get you started:

> DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, list VARCHAR(8000))
>
> SET NOCOUNT ON
>
> DECLARE @c INT, @p VARCHAR(8000), @cNext INT, @pNext VARCHAR(40)
>
> ```
>    DECLARE c CURSOR FOR 
>
>    SELECT CategoryId, ProductName 
>
>      FROM Northwind..Products 
>
>     ORDER BY CategoryId, ProductName ;
>
>    OPEN c ;
>
>    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @cNext, @pNext ;
>
>    SET @c = @cNext ;
>
>    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN 
>
>         IF @cNext > @c BEGIN 
>
>              INSERT @tbl SELECT @c, @p ;
>
>              SELECT @p = @PNext, @c = @cNext ;
>
>         END ELSE 
>
>              SET @p = COALESCE(@p + ',', SPACE(0)) + @pNext ;
>
>         FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @cNext, @pNext 
>
>    END 
>
>    INSERT @tbl SELECT @c, @p ;
>
>    CLOSE c ;
> ```
>
> DEALLOCATE c ;
>
> SELECT * FROM @tbl ;

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way to do it, not a lot of error checking, but it works...

```
DECLARE @theList VARCHAR(2000)
SET @theList =''

SELECT @TheList=@theList+[name]+','
FROM <tableName> WHERE [name] is not null

IF @@rowcount > 0
    SET @TheList=left(@TheList,len(@TheList)-1)

PRINT @theList
```